# Raster scan pattern python

Tags: python, list, plot

I am trying to create a list of xy positions that represent a raster scan pattern like below:

[image]

Simply put I am using nested loops and if else statements but it is getting messy. Is there a simple way generate a list of positions with a fixed step size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, using a mix of Numpy and normal Python:

```
from pylab import *

# define some grids
xgrid = arange(20, 31) 
ygrid = arange(10, 16)

xscan = []
yscan = []

for i, yi in enumerate(ygrid):
    xscan.append(xgrid[::(-1)**i]) # reverse when i is odd
    yscan.append(ones_like(xgrid) * yi)   

# squeeze lists together to vectors
xscan = concatenate(xscan)
yscan = concatenate(yscan)

# quick plot
plot(xscan, yscan, '.-')
axis([19, 31, 9, 16])
show()
```

The way this works is to define 2 empty lists for x and y, to which you append one scan-line at a time. For the x-coordinates, you alternatively need a forward and a backward line (`xgrid[::1]` for forward and `xgrid[::-1]` for backwards, the alternating `+1` and `-1` are obtained by `(-1)**i`), while for the y-coordinate, you have to repeat a single y-value for each x-coordinate. In the end, you have to [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the list of vectors into a single vector.

The same can be achieved without any for-loops using a list-comprehension and [`repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat),  like so:

```
xscan = concatenate([xgrid[::(-1)**i] for i in range(len(ygrid))])
yscan = repeat(ygrid, len(xgrid))
```

Resulting scan pattern:
[image: raster scan]

Comment: Interesting, could you explain how the loop works? It seems relatively incomprehensible to me at my current level of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more explanation, I hope it is clear now. If not, try to work through some basic python and numpy tutorials.